# Special type of cord to splice a chewed up power cord on electric smoker?

Tags: electrical

The dog made a snack out of the power cord for [my electric smoker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LK2SAYA).

I was thinking I'd just splice on a replacement cord/plug, but realizing there may be some sort of special type for this.

The cord has the following text on it, which I'm sure means something, but I don't know what in regards to what type of cable to replace/splice with it.

> (UL) E254458 SJTOW 3X16A(1.31MM²) VW-1 105°C 300V KAI HUA C(UL) E254458 SJTOW 3X1.31MM²(16AWG) 105°C 300V FT1

So, what am I looking for at the hardware store?

[image]

Comment: If the plug end of the cable is regularly stored or used in the rain I would replace the entire cable with a new one with a moulded on plug to avoid water getting inside it.   If it's kept plugged in inside a waterproof outdoor receptacle box, you should be fine with one of the suggested answers.

Comment: How's the dog??

Comment: @DJohnM She's fine. Lucky for her the smoker was unplugged. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's thoughtful of the dog to trim the cord so close to the plug end, rather than in the middle!

A regular replacement cord end will do. I prefer to pay a few dollars extra for the "heavy duty" or "professional" or whatever they call it.. I find them easier to assemble than the cheapest options are, and they definitely feel more solid in operation. (image from [www.lockingpowercords.com](http://www.lockingpowercords.com))

[image: NEMA 5-15P cord end]

It's always a good idea to use an ohm meter to confirm which wire color connects with each blade on the old plug to be sure you get the new plug set up the same way.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to actually need to add some cable as well...about 3' of the original cable is missing. Which I'm guessing the dog buried somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> UL) E254458 SJTOW 3X16A(1.31MM²) VW-1 105°C 300V KAI HUA C(UL) E254458 SJTOW 3X1.31MM²(16AWG) 105°C 300V FT1

Wow, when people post all the cord text, it makes it super easy to answer.

The wire size is 16 AWG.

The cord type is SJTOW.

> - S - Extra Hard Service. Cables that begin with an S are rated for 600V service... ***except for***
> - SJ - Hard Service. Also called a "Junior Jacket," this cable is rated for 300V service.
> - T - Thermoplastic Jacket. Confusing, I know, but this is different from a TPE jacket. These cables are made with PVC.
> - O - Oil Resistant. Just like it sounds, the outer jacket of the cable is oil resistant.
> - OO - The addition of the extra "O" means that the outer jacket and the insulation are both oil resistant.
> - W - Weather and Water Resistant. Cabling rated for outdoor use.

Thanks to [Ericson](https://blog.ericson.com/blog/sjo..what-the-meanings-behind-the-letters-on-electrical-cables).

**Note that "S" cordage (STOW) is superior to "SJ" cordage (SJTOW)**.  Similarly, "OO" cord" is superior to "O" cord.

> So, what am I looking for at the hardware store?

The Website address for McMaster-Carr.

Seriously though, don't settle on what they have if it's inferior.
Check their options in three areas: a) line cords with a plug on one end and wires on the other; b) extension cords that you can lop the socket end off of, and c) loose cordage on the spool where you'd add your own plug.

Answer (score 0):

You want SJTOW 3x16guage.  Common power tool replacement cable.

Comment: I presume the voltage rating matters? For instance, there's [this from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bergen-Industries-6-ft-16-3-SJTW-3-Wire-Appliance-Power-Tool-Cord-PS613163/304711936) but it says it has a max rating of 125V, whereas my smoker cable mentions 300V.

Comment: Cable itself should be labelled for 300v, but would check before buying.  The max rating should be what is safe for it.

Comment: wire doesn't care about voltage, only current. Insulation cares about voltage. If you're using "110", then 125v wire is fine. Since you're having a splice, and smokers draw a fair bit of amps, might be worth going down to 14awg. Check the splice after running a while to make sure it's not getting hot. Better would be to rewire the whole pigtail. You could chop a cheap harbor fright extension cord for a cheap UL-rated grounded lead...